# How to listen to 'page loaded after a redirect' event in the WebEngine?

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2

I've been trying to automatize downloading a JDK distribution from oracle.com with WebEngine/WebView and experiencing issues with handling redirect at one of the pages. The problem is that it does not generate any kind of event I am aware of when the page is loaded.

I track down the occurring redirect by using `webEngine.locationProperty()`, so when this property changes I notice the redirect going on. But it is not being followed by a change of the `webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty()` and the element I require is not loaded.

I resolved the issue by starting a thread which is watching my specific element to appear by running jQuery selector, i.e. `webEngine.executeScript("$('#sso_username').length > 0")`.

Is there a better way to do this, may be to listen for some property to change when the page after a redirect will load?